# Is there a way to disable a plasmoid toolbox that pops up while mouse is over the widget/plasmoid?

Tags: linux, kde, plasma

When you hover any plasmoid, a vertical toolbox appears to the left. The toolbox contains the resize, refresh, settings and remove buttons. Is there a way to remove this small panel appearing on every mouse over or at least change the event on which it appears (eg. ctrl+right click). Right click offers the remove and settings options, but not refresh and resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your wallpaper and you'll see something like this popup menu:
[image]

Select "Lock Widgets" and the toolbox will disappear. You should unlock widgets only when you need to move/resize things around and lock them after.